My player movement script randomly sends the player in seemingly random directions sometimes
I am new to Unity and the following code is supposed to be a player movement script. Everything works as expected until every now and then, usually when multiple inputs are pressed in succesion, the player goes flying.
Here is the code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float yRotation;
    float jumpHeight = 5;
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;

    public CameraController cameraController;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        yRotation = cameraController.yRotation;
        float yRotationRad = yRotation * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        Debug.Log(rigidbody.velocity);
        Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            velocity += new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(yRotationRad) * speed, rigidbody.velocity.y, Mathf.Cos(yRotationRad) * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            velocity += new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(yRotationRad-Mathf.PI/2) * speed, rigidbody.velocity.y, Mathf.Cos(yRotationRad - Mathf.PI / 2) * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            velocity += new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(yRotationRad + Mathf.PI / 2) * speed, rigidbody.velocity.y, Mathf.Cos(yRotationRad + Mathf.PI / 2) * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            velocity += new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(yRotationRad + Mathf.PI) * speed, rigidbody.velocity.y, Mathf.Cos(yRotationRad + Mathf.PI) * speed);
        }


        if(velocity!= Vector3.zero)
        rigidbody.velocity = velocity;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && rigidbody.velocity.y == 0) {
            rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x,jumpHeight,rigidbody.velocity.z);
        }
    }
}

I expected for the player to move using wasd and space which does happen until the player goes flying. If there are any other issues in the code feel free to point those out aswell.

You're using a Rigidbody and want to add velocity when some inputs are holds.
Your issue is that you're forgetting to multiply the velocity you're adding by Time.deltaTime, this represents the time elapsed since the last update. If you don't use it, you'll have a random behavior depending on your framerate.
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    velocity += new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(yRotationRad) * speed, rigidbody.velocity.y, Mathf.Cos(yRotationRad) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
//Add Time.deltaTime each time you want to make something framerate  independent (movement, timer, ...)

Also, it's encouraged to use Update() only for the logic, if you want to play with Physics try to do it in FixedUpdate().
See this for more information.
(if you move your code from Update() to FixedUpdate(), replace Time.deltaTime by Time.fixedDeltaTime)
When you become more familiar with Unity I encourage you to give a try to the new Unity input system.

On every input, especially when you press more than one button, you are increasing the velocity of the Rigidbody higher than it was in the previous frame (at least for the Y coordinate). That is why your character starts flying.
First of all, you shouldn't use the Update() callback for any physics calculations - its frequency depends on the frame rate. Use FixedUpdate() instead.
Secondly, setting the velocity of a Rigidbody to move a character doesn't seem like a good idea. I suggest you consider implementing simple movement by updating the transform.position of an object. Another option could be the CharacterController component.

When you're using a Rigibody, there's 3 ways to move it, and updating transform. Position directly is a wrong one because you're ignoring collision.
You can use :

rigibody.MovePosition(Vector3 new position) to move it to a new place
change the velocity like it's done by the author
rigibody.AddForce https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html


@AlexiCourieux, I wouldn't say changing position directly will ignore collisions fully, but in general, of course, it is not recommended to mix physics-based movement with simple one, that is true. But the question is, does the author need collisions at all? It isn't mentioned in his post.

I see what you're meaning, but because he use a dynamic rigidbody I assumed it was the case. I just want to say that using the velocity is not wrong, my game is working exactly like that because I have advanced mechanics where I don't want to handle the physics by myself but still want to affect the velocity in precise ways and it's doing well.
Use of transform.position is good when you want to ignore collisions, especially when you want to teleport the character somewhere.
